# why this error has come ? "static declaration of function follows non-static declaration"?

Tags: c, static-functions

I am learning about static function and as per rule if i declare function as 
a static function then i can't access this function into other c file and if i try to access then there should be an error "**undefined reference to `fun**"
so i declare and define static function into add.c and add.h file and call that function into main.c file but i am getting different error i.e "**static declaration of 'fun' follows non-static declaration**"**strong text**
so my question is that why this error has come ????
please forgive me for my poor English !!!!

```
/************** main.c****************/
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "add.h"

    int main(void)
    {
      printf("%d ", fun());
      printf("%d ", fun());
      return 0;
    }

/***************add.c*************/

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "add.h"

    static int fun(void)
    {
      int a=5,b=4;
      return a+b;
    }

/*********************add.h*************/

    #ifndef ADD_H_
    #define ADD_H_

    static int fun(void);

    #endif /* ADD_H_ */
```

Comment: Since static functions are file-local, it makes no sense at all to put static function declarations in header files.  In this case, you can't make `fun` static in `add.c` if you want to call it from `main.c`.  Different files, right?  So decide:  either (a) static, one file only, not in header file, or (b) non-static, in header file, callable from any file.  Choose.

Comment: Hey tom thanks for understanding this 
!!!!

Comment: I am tempted to reopen this question because it is not a duplicate of the purported original. This question asks why OP gets an error message stating “static declaration of function follows non-static declaration”, and that is not explained in the original. However, it does not seem the code in the question should generate that message, so there is probably a mismatch between the code and the question. The question should have been clarified or closed with a different reason, such as no longer reproducible or unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static variable or a function is seen only in the file where it is declared.

C11 standard

> **6.2.2.3**
>
> If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a
>   function contains the storage-class specifier **static**, the
>   identifier has **internal linkage**.